# how can i use map[string][string] in go to typemap to map<string, string> in c++?

Tags: string, dictionary, swig

When I use `%template(map_string_string) map<string, string>` in my swig.i,
then a function like that in c++:

```
void add(map<string, string>& map_){
// code implementation.
}
```

After I use comand: swig -go -cgo -intgosize 64 -c++ swig.i,
a interface.go generated:

```
// part of my interface.go
type Map_string_string interface {
    Swigcptr() uintptr
    SwigIsMap_string_string()
    Size() (_swig_ret uint)
    Empty() (_swig_ret bool)
    Clear()
    Get(arg2 string) (_swig_ret string)
    Set(arg2 string, arg3 string)
    Del(arg2 string)
    Has_key(arg2 string) (_swig_ret bool)
}
```

then, I call the add function in main.go, but failed.

```
var argcInfo = make(map[string]string)
add(argcInfo)
```

I want to use swig to generate a interface for this function add(map<string, string>& map_) in go,
how can i do that?
Thanks for your time and reply.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that calling add fails ? Do you have an error message ?

Comment: Show your [mcve] with the complete .i file.  You may be missing an `%include` and declaration order can matter.